# blocking 'Join' method on html5 webworker

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

I implemented a Thread class in js similar to the Thread class in .net/c#:

```js
function Thread(func) {
    var o = this;
    o.func = func;
}

Thread.prototype.Start = function (p, cb) {
    var o = this;

    var toClass = {}.toString;
    var wcode = "" + o.func;
    var re = /\((.*?)\)/;
    var rearr = re.exec(wcode)[1].split(",");
    var odta = {};
    var tobj = [];
    var pstr = "";
    for (var i = rearr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        odta[rearr[i]] = p ? p[i] : p;
        pstr += rearr[i] + "=" + rearr[0] + ".data." + rearr[i] + ";";
        if (p && p[i] && (toClass.call(p[i]) == "[object ArrayBuffer]")) {
          //  tobj[tobj.length] = p;
          //  trace("added arraybuffer");
        }
    }

    wcode = wcode.replace("{", "{" + pstr);
    re = /return ([^;\}]*?)([;\}])/g;
    wcode = wcode.replace(re, "postMessage($1)$2");
    //trace("re:" + wcode);
    var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = " + wcode ]);
    // Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
    worker.onmessage = function (e) {
        trace("callback from worker " + e.data);
        if (cb)
            cb(e.data);
    };
    worker.postMessage(odta, tobj);


};
```

Now I'd like to implement the 'Join' method, i.e. wait for the webworker to finish (or send a message indicating it's done). I know I could use a timer but that wouldn't preserve the context of the caller, closures are also not what I'm looking for, it shouyld be a 'real' blocking call.

It should work with Chrome & FF (I've already given up on IE).

Is there any way to make such a blocking call just like .net's join-method?

Comment: _"Now I'd like to implement the 'Join' method, i.e. wait for the webworker to finish (or send a message indicating it's done)"_ What does worker do? Is `postMessage` not returning expected result? What does `Join` method do?

Comment: The Join method should wait for completion of the workers, I'd be doing something like 'for(i=0; i<numworkers;i++) worker[i].Join();', after that all postMessage calls should have arrived and all data should be available...

Comment: After all `postMessage` calls have arrived from worker threads?

Comment: yes, so without using a callback function (as it is now), blocking the main ui thread until they're all done, that's how the .net implementation works and I'd like the js and c# versions to be as similar as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to block main thread? Or not block main thread until all workers have posted a message?

Comment: what I want is to start all the workers (4 of them, they'll be doing some cryptographic hashing which now takes 18 seconds on my machine), maybe do some other stuff on the main thread and then block and wait until all the workers are finished

Comment: Note, you can also pass a named or anonymous function to `Blob`, use `FileReader()`, `.readAsText()` , `Function()` to convert string back into function

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `Promise` constructor, `Promise.all()`

```
function handleWorker(/* args */) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // create worker, do stuff
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
      resolve(/* optionally pass a value */)
    }
    worker.onerror = function(err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}

var workers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  workers.push(handleWorkers(/* arg */))
}

Promise.all(workers)
.then(res => console.log("all workers have posted message", res));
// handle error
.catch(function(workerError) {
  console.log(workerError)
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yo8r3fzw/

Answer (score 0):

As I have been developing a multhreading JS API supporting concurrent programming ([OODK-JS](https://github.com/GOMServices/oodk-js-oop-for-js)) I could give this straight answer:

it not possible to block a thread waiting for a signal coming from an another thread.

Why?

because webworkers communicate with the main thread by message exchange. A good try would be implementing an infinite loop in the main thread and setting as stop condition a variable which will be updated when the main thread received a message from the webworker to break the loop. Unfortunately, as the main thread is looping , messages from webworkers are not received until the loop is done as it is the main thread keep looping indefinitively.

Solution?

blocking the main thread is not possible but it is still possible to trigger an action when all webwokers has finished their job by implementing a counter incremented each time a webworker send the message 'task.done' for example. Once the counter has reached the number of webworkers initialized, an action can be triggered

Comment: Triggering an action/function is what I was trying to avoid, I'd like to continue in the same function that calls the Join method. I'm starting to think this will be the accepted answer though...

Comment: I objectively think it is, web worker has been designed to execute tasks that the main thread could not performed without heavily impacting the user experience. Still advanced concepts as locks, concurrent calls, object properties synchronization can be implemented through message exchange (i.e implementing a queue of tasks following the producer/consumer design pattern is achievable) to simulate a standard mutli-threading environment

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the suggestion by guest271314 but not there yet, was hoping the static Promise.resolve would block as the documentation says it returns a 'resolved' promise. Here's what I have so far:

```js
function Thread(func) {
    var o = this;
    o.func = func;
}

Thread.prototype.Start = function (p, cb) {
    var o = this;

    var toClass = {}.toString;
    var wcode = "" + o.func;
    trace(wcode);
    var re = /\((.*?)\)/;
    var rearr = re.exec(wcode)[1].split(",");
    var odta = {};
    var tobj = [];
    var pstr = "";
    for (var i = rearr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        odta[rearr[i]] = p ? p[i] : p;
        pstr += rearr[i] + "=" + rearr[0] + ".data." + rearr[i] + ";";
        if (p && p[i] && (toClass.call(p[i]) == "[object ArrayBuffer]")) {
            tobj[tobj.length] = p[i];
            //  trace("added arraybuffer");
        }
    }

    wcode = wcode.replace("{", "{" + pstr);
    re = /return ([^;\}]*?)([;\}])/g;
    wcode = wcode.replace(re, "postMessage($1);return;$2");
    //trace("re:" + wcode);
    var blob = new Blob(["onmessage = " + wcode ]);
    // Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);

    o.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        worker.onmessage = function (e) {
            trace("callback from worker " + e.data);
            if (cb)
                cb(e.data);
            resolve();
        };
    });
    worker.postMessage(odta, tobj);
};

Thread.prototype.Join = function () {
    var o = this;
    Promise.resolve(o.promise);
    // I'd like to get here AFTER the worker has finished
};
```

And testing it with:

```js
 var t = new Thread(myfunction);
 t.Start([1, 2, 3, new ArrayBuffer(2)]);
 t.Join();
 trace("Thread done!");
```

Comment: _"// I'd like to get here AFTER the worker has finished"_ Use `.then()` chained to `Promise.resolve(o.promise);` . You can also `return` `Promise.resolve(o.promise);` from `t.Join()` call and chain another `.then()` to `t.Join()` with `trace()` call inside of `.then()` function; for `trace()` to be called after `t.Join()`. `Thread.prototype.Join = function () {
    var o = this;
    return Promise.resolve(o.promise).then(function() {//this portion complete});
    // I'd like to get here AFTER the worker has finished
};`, `t.Join().then(function() {trace("Thread done!")})`